# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. when create table structure

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and face this type of error related to key in this table structure.
in this code, we create table for fetch employee data fro particular API and display it in table formate but for id, there is some missing in code I read so many solutions for that but I don't what is a change in core .

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap';

class EmployeeList extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {emps:[]}
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.refreshList();
}

refreshList(){
    fetch('https://localhost:44339/api/employee')
    .then(response=> response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({emps:data})
    });

}
    render()
    {
        const {emps} = this.state;
        return(
            <Table className="mt-4" striped bordered hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>FirstName</th>
                        <th>LastName</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {emps.map(emps =>
                        <tr key ={emps.Id}> 
                        <td>{emps.Id}</td>
                        <td>{emps.FirstName}</td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        )
    }
}

export default EmployeeList;
```

- please suggest me how to solve this in this code.
  thanks

Comment: Your code seems fine, maybe the error comes from other source.

Comment: Can you paste the error log or its photo ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have `Id` in `emps` data.
Instead you can pass `index`.

```
           <tbody>
                {emps.map((emps,index) =>
                    <tr key ={index}> 
                    <td>{emps.Id}</td>
                    <td>{emps.FirstName}</td>
                    </tr>
                    )}
            </tbody>
```